# UIScrollView: Zoom to fit screen width

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview

I am trying to make an image fit the screen width - with an image within a UIScrollView:

```
myImageView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "image.png"))
scrollView = UIScrollView(frame: view.bounds)
let w = myImageView.bounds.width
let h = myImageView.bounds.height
let r = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: w, height: h)
scrollView.zoomToRect(r, animated: false)
scrollView.delegate = self

scrollView.addSubview(myImageView)
view.addSubview(scrollView)
```

Can you?

Comment: why don't you set `UIImageView`'s `contentMode` property

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
myImageView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "image.png"))
myImageView.frame = view.bounds
myImageView.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFill
view.addSubview(myImageView)
```